# Why was I not included in the *marked as duplicate by* legend in the close banner?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I just flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205642/how-to-hide-console-log-in-python-pyinstaller) as a duplicate. My "Potential Duplicate" got 5 upvotes, and finally it was closed as a duplicate. But my name was not included in the closed post-notice banner.

> marked as duplicate by ....

Why was I not included in the names? Is it due to my reputation, or is it a bug?

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Why didn't my name show up when I marked a question duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216477/289905).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have the [Close Vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), so you only *flagged* the post - the listed names are the users who actually cast the votes to close it. You'll gain that privilege at 3,000 reputation.